# UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed when sending email in Python

Tags: python, smtplib

I am following a tutorial in which I run the following code.

```
import smtplib

email_user = 'email@gmail.com'
email_send = 'email@gmail.com'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,'pass')

message = 'Hello'
server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,message)
server.quit()
```

Unfortunately, the code is throwing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lol\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\encodings\idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lol/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello.py", line 27, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  File "C:\Users\lol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\smtplib.py", line 261, in __init__
    fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
  File "C:\Users\lol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Noobis!  What line does this error occur at?  Could you try executing the Python one line at a time in your interpreter and tell us where the actual error happens?  Thanks!

Comment: @Max Hmm seems to occur at `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)`

Comment: @Noobis: Please post the full traceback (not just the last line).

Comment: @Blender Edited

Comment: @Noobis: Does `import socket; socket.getfqdn()` fail for you? That seems to be the problem. What is your computer hostname?

Comment: @Blender Yes, it does. My hostname is PC-BENQ...